# Making safe ajax calls with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I noticed that certain characters entered in text box and sent through Jquery Ajax request 
as parms are being mis-interpretted. (at least from my point of view).
The "&" creates a new unwanted parm. 
The "+" disappears entirely.

I want to get value of text box and convert to html entities. Something like this I think:

SafeParm = $("#myDIV").val().html();

Any other recommendations for making for making safe ajax calls with jQuery are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

use want the escape function:

```
SafeParm = escape($("#myDIV").val().html());
```

Comment: escape will not properly encode "+". See http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Answer (score 2):

In this case, [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) is what you want. There are weird edge cases where `escape` may not do exactly what you want it to. See: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the parameters passed to a request.

See [Encoding html using javascript's escape & unescape](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/html/encode.html)

You can escape `$("#myDIV").val()` where myDiv is the id of your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

`escape` is deprecated. Use `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`.